# Legitamate cross site communication

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web-applications

I am building a website, within a large intranet, that wraps and adds functionality to another site within the same intranet. I do not have access to the other site's source and they do not provide any api's for the functionality they provide. I need to, somehow, have my server-side code go to that site, fill in some forms, then press a submit button.

Is this possible? If so, how can I accomplish this?



Note: I am working in asp.NET if that matters at all.

Answer (score 2):

Not the most efficient, but maybe WatiN can get you started:

http://watin.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

Just look at the URL the form is supposed to submit to and the method it employs (POST or GET) and then send a request to that URL using the same method and put the field you want as parameters

Answer (score 0):

Your server-side code is basically a web client to the other web site. You will need to write the code to send the HTML form data to the other web site and process the response. I would start with the System.Net.WebClient class. Take a look at [System.Net.WebClient.UploadValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144246.aspx). That class/method will enable you to POST the form data to the web site via a [NameValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx).